# Finding the mean of a random variable in an equation given standard deviation and mean

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, standard-deviation

Please help! What do I plug into these equations to solve for the mean of Z??

Suppose that X is a random variable with mean 23 and standard deviation 5. Also suppose that Y is a random variable with mean 40 and standard deviation 9. Find the mean of the random variable  for each of the following cases:

Z= 2 + 10X,
Z= 2X - 10,
Z= X + Y,
Z= X - Y, and
Z= -5X - 2Y

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**:

- $\mathbb E(U+V)=\mathbb E(U)+\mathbb E(V)$.
- $\mathbb E(cU)=c\mathbb E(U)$ where $c$ denotes a constant.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand! I have no idea where "U" and "V" come from, nor do I understand how I'm to use the std. dev. and mean to solve each of these equations.

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are random variables, and the letters are just arbitrary. According to your question you must find the means of ... In none of these cases the standard deviation plays any part.

Comment: I see. So I should ignore the standard deviations. Does the "E" in each case denote summation? I'm sorry. These Z= equations are really throwing me off. I suppose I'm to plug the corresponding X/Y means into each equation? Thank you!

Comment: $\mathbb E$ stands for 'expectation' wich is in this context the same as 'mean'. I will give you one example that is in your question: if $Z=X+Y$ then you find the mean of $Z$ by $\mathbb E(Z)=\mathbb E(X+Y)=\mathbb E(X)+\mathbb E(Y)=23+40=63$.

Comment: Excellent! That's all I needed, thank you. What if the question was the same, only asking for standard deviation and variance as opposed to mean?

Comment: I am glad to help, but I leave it here. If you want to have answer on the question in your comment, then just ask a new question on this site. Comments are actually not meant to go on with new questions. Cheers :).